# Duality relation of Banach spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

It is well known that the $L^p$ space for $p\ge1$ is dual space of $L^q$ where $q$ is Hölder conjugate, and they have an following relation:
$$
\|f\|_{L^p} = \sup_{\|g\|_{L^q}=1}\langle f,g \rangle_{L^{2}}
$$
for $f\in L^p$ and $g\in L^q$. Moreover, this duality relation is able to not only Sobolev space $H^s$ and its dual $H^{-s}$ but also Wiener amalgam space $W(p,p')$ and $W(q,q')$.

Since they are Banach spaces, I expect that

> For any Banach function space $X$ and its dual $X^*$,
> $$
> \|f\|_{X}=  \sup_{\|g\|_{X^*}=1}\langle f,g \rangle_{L^{2}}
> $$
> with some additional conditions.

But I cannot find any references or prove yet. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The notation $\langle x, y \rangle_{L^{2}}$ is very strange. Where does $L^{2}$ inner product come from in a genaral Banach space?

Comment: What if I assume that $X$ is Banach 'function' space in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$? Then its $L^2$ inner product can be defined as $\int f g dx$.

Comment: The dual space of a Banach function space is not necessarily a Banach function space. I suggest to look at chapter 15 of the book "Integration" by Zaanen. In particular sections 69 and 71.